# Extract value from background-image style attribute with PHP

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I have a following HTML code:

```
<div class="article__img has-caption" style="background-image: url('img/main/article-plug.png')" >
```

I'm trying to extract an image URL and replace it with another (for example img/main/article-plug.webp) but I'm stuck with XPath queries and don't know what to do.

Thanks for help in advance!

That's my last code (but it doesn't return anything yet):

```
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($article["DESCRIPTION"]);

$domXPath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);

$img = $domXPath->query('substring-before(substring-after(//div[@class=\'article__img has-caption\']/@style, "background-image: url(\'"), "\')")');
```

Comment: Related: [Selecting background url from style attribute with XPATH (and PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7333278/2943403) and [How to extract an image URL from a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64921486/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, with a help from [dlporter98](https://stackoverflow.com/users/970239/dlporter98) I was able to solve my problem, here is a code if someone will face the same problem:

```
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8"));

$domXPath  = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$divs = $domXPath->evaluate("//div[@class=\"article__img has-caption\"]");
foreach ($divs as $div) {
    $style = $div->getAttribute("style");

    $url = $domXPath->evaluate("substring-before(substring-after(@style, \"background-image: url('\"), \"')\")", $div);

    $div->setAttribute("style", str_replace($url, Webp::getFromUrl($url), $style));
}

$html = mb_convert_encoding($domDocument->saveHTML(), "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES");
```